# Creating arrays in Python3 using multiplication

Tags: python-3.x

From the Python ctypes library, I can create an array of c_floats like this:

```
my_array = c_float * 10
```

but if I try this with int

```
my_array = int * 10
```

I get an error message. What's different?

Comment: The difference is that `c_float` supports multiplication (in the metaclass), `int` does not.

Comment: You can do something similar `my_list = [int] * 10`

Comment: @Mark: no, this will construct a list of references to the `int` *class*. You can do something equivalent with `[0]*10`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I shouldn't have used `int` when what I meant was any integer, sorry.